# Make a diagram using only connectable arrows

Tags: microsoft-visio

I want to make a simple diagram that consists of arrows.  Each arrow has a label above it.  I have this by just using a connector, making it straight, and telling the text to sit above it.

Now I want to connect those arrows to one another and have them stick.  Bu they are connectors, not "objects", so won't connect to each other.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use DIA?? You could try to use Gane&Sarson Dataflow Model Diagrams. I have made some Diagrams with this tool and the connections functions well.